# Can't make Django ModelForm Select Choice Field work in Template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I tried multiple solutions around but couldn't make my select field work in Django Template. I am beginner and humbly apologize if my question is not up to standard. My select button is not showing any options in django form. I only have two options to show. Is there anyway I can get form field without having iterate through it in template? Using Django 3 and Python 3.8. Help will be much appreciated.

Model:

```
class User(AbstracUser):
   ACC_TYPE = (('Student', 'Student'), ('Teacher', 'Teacher'))
   role = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=ACC_TYPE
   .....
```

Form:

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm): #Using django's default form
      account_type = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=User.ACC_TYPE))
      model = User
      fields =('.............,
              'account_type')
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['account_type'].choices = [(each[0], each[1]) for each in User.ACC_TYPE]
        self.fields['account_type'].required = True
```

Template:

```
     .......
     <select>
     {% for opt, val in form.account_type.choices %}
      <option value="{{ opt }}">{{ value }}</option>
     {% endfor %}
     </select>
     ......
```

Comment: did you try calling super's init #after# setting choices

Comment: maybe that will help. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example

Comment: Yes I did. Please look into question posted above.

Comment: There is no reason that it shouldn't show up the form with fields you are trying to get. Are you using some customized theme for HTML5 or Bootstrap?

Comment: That's true I am using customized commercial theme from themeforest.net and its Bootstrap4 Material Design theme.

Comment: Ahhh! got it. I will post the answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is fine. You shouldn't be having this issue. Only reason could be and its a long shot...that you are using some bootstrap theme with customized CSS classes in it. Now either you load those custom classes per field or you can use django-crispy-fields that inherits all classes with form-group. You will need to load the form with {{ form|crispy }}. For details please check settings for django-crispy-forms. Remember to load the tag at top of page where you want to use it as per settings {% load crispy_forms_tags %}. Read Docs [here](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/d-0/index.html).

Comment: That worked. But I couldn't understand the login of your answer.

Comment: Logic is simple. When you create HTML document or lets say a Bootstrap template from getbootstrap.com. You can create a form and default styling is supported by Django's template system. For instance lets say you load any class for form it will bring relevant CSS to that class. But when you are using some kind of theme that just might not have default classes like on getbootstrap.com. For now this logic is enough I don't want to burden you with extra details. Please read docs and have some grip for HTML/CSS with Django.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks a lot for help. This platform rocks :-)